# how entity framework working

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Please refer to this picture:

[image: this picture]

This table data are fetched with *Entity Framework*. When I double click the `EmailID` and change it, the data will be  updated to SQL Server automatically.

Here it's web api code about update:

```
// PUT: api/Subscriber/5
public void Put(tbl_Subscribers sub)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        myEntity.Entry(sub).State = EntityState.Modified;
        try
        {
            myEntity.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

When this code run, the modified `emailID` has been updated to SQL Server, no need any sql state, no need `ID`, how it update the code？

AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.updSubscriber = function (sub, eve) {
    sub.MailID = eve.currentTarget.innerText;//get EmailID
    var upd = APIService.updateSubscriber(sub);//update EmailID
    upd.then(function (d) {
        getAll();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while updating the data.')
    })
};
```

Angular Service:

```
this.updateSubscriber = function (sub) {
return $http({
    method: 'put',
    data: sub,
    url: 'api/Subscriber'
});
```

}

Hope some one could help me explain it.

Comment: `how it update the code` <= I am not understanding your question. What is it you are wanting to do exactly....

Comment: Please refer to screenshot.

Comment: Return the updated model from the `put` method and then update your model in angular from the result.

Comment: *no need any sql state* Well... I don't know what you mean by *sql* state, but you set `sub`'s *entity* state to `Modified`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, we need not any sql state, the data has been bound. so the EF will identify them automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like every row subscribe to a wep API function. The function uses Angular JS to make async call to your code behind.

Then, ain't no magic here :

```
    myEntity.Entry(sub).State = EntityState.Modified;
    try
    {
        myEntity.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Sub contain informations about what has been modified on your entity.

Once `db.SaveChages()` is reached, it looks for what modifications should be made in your db, there is only one at the time so it's probably very fast.

Entity Framework write it's own db query on the backend, you can't see them unless you use a profiler.